# Is it possible to implement a C# constructor without using the class name?

Tags: c#, constructor

When looking at disassembled .NET assemblies I notice that constructors are defined as "**.ctor**". Is that possible to do in the actual code?

Comment: This is a very valid question which shouldn't be sneered at. I like that Rust has `new` & `Self` to avoid code repetition. But unfortunately C# doesn't have similar thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, if you write in [`IL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) not if you write in C# though.

Answer (score 3):

Dont see the point why you want this.

You can use the VS snippet ctor and you get a free constructor.

Just type ctor and press two times the tab-key.

Answer (score 3):

RE:

> Damn ... it is much easier to use
>   that in code snippets

Is this for Visual Studio code snippets? They already have one called ctor that substitutes the class name. You could look at the definition of that if its default behaviour is not what you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>ctor</Title>
            <Shortcut>ctor</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for constructor</Description>
            <Author>Microsoft Corporation</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal Editable="false">
                    <ID>classname</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Class name</ToolTip>
                    <Function>ClassName()</Function>
                    <Default>ClassNamePlaceholder</Default>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[public $classname$ ()
    {
        $end$
    }]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is only a syntactic difference between C# and IL.  You need to call out the class name when defining the constructor in your C# code.  What are you looking to accomplish?

Comment: Can't be bothered to type the class name, or to answer?  Can't say I'm with you on either one.